# How to remove white fuzziness from image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to remove the background from product images, save them as transparent png's and got to a point where I can't figure out how and why I get the white line around the products like a fuzziness(see second image) don't know the real word for the effect. Also I'm losing the Nike swoosh which is white too :(

[image: input]
[image: output]

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()


newData = []


for item in datas:
    if item[0] > 247 and item[1] > 247 and item[2] > 247:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

Any ideas how I can fix this so I get clean selections, edges ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a copy of your image and use PIL/Pillow's ImageDraw.floodfill() to flood fill from the top-left corner using a reasonable tolerance - that way you will only fill to the edges of the shirt and avoid the Nike logo.

Then take the background outline and make it white and everything else black and try applying some morphology (from scikit-image maybe) to dilate the white a little larger to hide the jaggies.

Finally, put the resulting new layer into the image with `putalpha()`.

---

I am really pushed for time, but here are the bones of it. Just missing the copy of the original image at the start and the `putalpha()` of the new alpha layer back at the end...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

# Open the shirt
im = Image.open('shirt.jpg')

# Make all background pixels (not including Nike logo) into magenta (255,0,255)
ImageDraw.floodfill(im,xy=(0,0),value=(255,0,255),thresh=10)

# DEBUG
im.show()
```

[image]

Experiment with the threshold (`thresh`) here. If you make it 50, it works much more cleanly and may be good enough to stop.

```
# Make into Numpy array
n = np.array(im)

# Mask of magenta background pixels
bgMask =(n[:, :, 0:3] == [255,0,255]).all(2)

# DEBUG
Image.fromarray((bgMask*255).astype(np.uint8)).show()
```

[image]

```
# Make a disk-shaped structuring element
strel = skimage.morphology.disk(13)

# Perform a morphological closing with structuring element
closed = skimage.morphology.binary_closing(bgMask,selem=strel)

# DEBUG
Image.fromarray((closed*255).astype(np.uint8)).show()
```

[image]

If you are unfamiliar with morphology, Anthony Thyssen has some excellent noes worth reading [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/).

By the way, you could also use `potrace` to smooth the outline somewhat.

---

I had a bit more time today so here is a more complete version. You can experiment with the morphology disk sizes and floodfill thresholds according to your images till you find something tailored for your needs:

```
#!/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

# Open the shirt and make a clean copy before we dink with it too much
im = Image.open('shirt.jpg')
orig = im.copy()

# Make all background pixels (not including Nike logo) into magenta (255,0,255)
ImageDraw.floodfill(im,xy=(0,0),value=(255,0,255),thresh=50)

# DEBUG
im.show()

# Make into Numpy array
n = np.array(im)

# Mask of magenta background pixels
bgMask =(n[:, :, 0:3] == [255,0,255]).all(2)

# DEBUG
Image.fromarray((bgMask*255).astype(np.uint8)).show()

# Make a disk-shaped structuring element
strel = skimage.morphology.disk(13)

# Perform a morphological closing with structuring element to remove blobs
newalpha = skimage.morphology.binary_closing(bgMask,selem=strel)

# Perform a morphological dilation to expand mask right to edges of shirt
newalpha = skimage.morphology.binary_dilation(newalpha, selem=strel)

# Make a PIL representation of newalpha, converting from True/False to 0/255
newalphaPIL = (newalpha*255).astype(np.uint8)
newalphaPIL = Image.fromarray(255-newalphaPIL, mode='L')

# DEBUG
newalphaPIL.show()

# Put new, cleaned up image into alpha layer of original image
orig.putalpha(newalphaPIL)
orig.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

As regards using `potrace` to smooth the outline, you would save `new alphaPIL` as a PGM format image because that is what `potrace` likes as input. So that would be:

```
newalphaPIL.save('newalpha.pgm')
```

Now you can play around, oops I meant *"experiment carefully"* with `potrace` to smooth the alpha outline. The basic command is:

```
potrace -b pgm newalpha.pgm -o smoothalpha.pgm
```

You can then re-load the image `smoothalpha.pgm` back into your Python and use it on the last line in the `putalpha()` call. Here is an animation of the difference between the original unsmoothed alpha and the smoothed one:

[image]

Look carefully at the edges to see the difference. You may want to experiment with resizing the alpha either to twice the size or half the size before smoothing to see what effect that has.

Comment: I like your solution, sounds like it would work. would appreciate a piece of code to try it on some images, if I'm not asking too much.

Comment: I have added some code to get you started. Note that the ugliness results from using JPEG to store your images.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! everything you wrote is so new to me :) gotta run it step by step to understand the process...wanna see the real png to understand/compare the result you are getting...

Comment: I put some more debug statements in and interspersed the corresponding images to make it clearer.

Comment: It seems like you are using libraries other then `PIL`, namely `Scipy/skimage` etc. But their corresponding imports are not mentioned in the code. (I am not aware of those libraries so I can't imports them myself)

Comment: @Mark Setchell can't thank you enough ! got an error :     strel = skimage.morphology.disk(13)
NameError: name 'skimage' is not defined

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Sorry! I always try to include my **imports** but sometimes I  miss some because I test my code interactively in `IPython` and I sometimes miss a step when finalising my answer. I have added it in `import skimage.morphology`

Comment: @VasuDeo.S In case you are unfamiliar with `scikit-image`, I install it like this on macOS... `pip3 install scikit-image`

Comment: I addressed the imports issue, as the OP stated that "*everything you wrote is new to me*", so OP may not be familiar with the libraries involved in the code. So I though if you add them to your answer, It would be easier for the OP to follow.

Comment: I have added more comments and references to my answer to help you along as it is all new to you.

Comment: You guys rock ! What I've learned so far : filling the background with Magenta ! Find it very useful ! Played with threshold, also really nice, something new ! Still don't understand the morphology part and looks very interesting and promising the POTRACE part. The biggest dummest question is how do I save a clean transparent png ? Played with putalpha, no luck :(  If you can open my eyes a bit please. Thank you very much !

Comment: I had a bit more time so I added a bit more at the end of my answer - please have another look.

Comment: I have added some more about `potrace` not sure if it is worth the effort. There is also a Python version if you find you like it... https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/